# What's the fastest way to produce rolling window embeddings in time series data?

Tags: pandas, datetime, time-series

I'm interested in transforming a typical time series dataset (one dimension) into a matrix consisting of every possible sequential combination of the original one. My stride is always 1 (might change in the future), window size should change according to preference, overlaps are encouraged and my focus is intraday data, meaning that combinations can only stem from the same day, one day at a time.

Here is a sample dataset

```
import pandas as pd
date_1 = pd.date_range('2015-02-24', periods=5, freq='1T')
date_2 = pd.date_range('2015-02-25', periods=5, freq='1T')
date = date_1.union(date_2)
values = range(len(date))

df = pd.DataFrame({'date': date, 'values': values})
```

Given a window size of 3, do you know of any fast, preferably Pythonic way to end up with the following output

```
0 1 2
1 2 3
2 3 4
5 6 7
6 7 8
7 8 9
```

I've messed around with `group_by` but wasn't able to come up with the demonstrated result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group the column `values` on `date` then inside a list comprehension iterate over each group and apply the `sliding_window_view` transformation, then vertically stack all the sliding views corresponding to each group

For numpy version >= `1.20`

```
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view

grp = df['values'].groupby(df['date'].dt.floor('D'))
np.vstack([sliding_window_view(v, 3) for _, v in grp])
```

For numpy version < `1.20`

```
def sliding_view(a, w):
    s = a.strides[0]
    shape = a.shape[0] - w + 1, w
    return np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(a, shape, (s, s))


grp = df['values'].groupby(df['date'].dt.floor('D'))
np.vstack([sliding_view(v.values, 3) for _, v in grp])
```

---

```
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [2, 3, 4],
       [5, 6, 7],
       [6, 7, 8],
       [7, 8, 9]])
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, how to also measure time in each loop?

Comment: @civy you can run `timeit` analysis on the code block

Comment: Weird, I'm getting ImportError: cannot import name 'sliding_window_view' from 'numpy.lib.stride_tricks'

Comment: @civy `sliding_window_view` is added in numpy version `1.20`.  I've included an alternate solution in case you have numpy version < `1.20` installed on your system